# How to localize javascript files in a Struts 2 app

Tags: struts2

I wrote an Struts 2 application and want to localize it. Now I am using javascript and I would like to put the scripts out of my HTML template to an own javascript file.

When I do it, my s:text tags are not rendered (of course).

Question is how can I localize my javascript files with Struts 2 in a clean way? I would like to avoid to use another technique than the properties files i currently use.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: can you post some of your current code?

Comment: Not sure if my code is of any help here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with your resource bundles back at server, one way possible would be to save your javascript files as .jsp file and serve them with an action so this way your struts tags in your javascript files will get a chance to retrieve the data from server and return the file upon request.
Personally I prefer to keep client messages in javascript files and server messages in resource bundles. This way you can save a .jsp processing IMHO.

Comment: Yes I guessed I need to do it like that. I don't like the struts processing of a js file too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden field in your JSP and pass its id to the external JavaScript file and get its value like follows.

In your JSP,

```
<s:hidden id="warning" value="%{getText('propertyKey')}"/>
```

(hidden field poplated with the value of the property key in the resource bundle)

Call your external JS method from the same JSP,

```
<s:a href="%{deleteSelected}">
<img src="<s:url value='/images/delete.gif'/>" border="none" 
        onclick="javascript:return displayWarning('warning')"/>
</s:a>
```

In external JavaScript file,

```
function displayWarning(message) {
    var ret = true;
    ret = confirm(document.getElementById(message).value);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Hidden fields actually are an option. It is not the solution i am really glad about, but it is one. Maybe I will create a JavaScript array in the header of the jsp template then. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: its ok... just wanted to show you a way.. :) BTW if you found a solution, please don't forget to post your solution... i also have the same problem.Thanks.

Comment: The solution of hidden fields served me and I am happy with that solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mytxt='<s:text name="my.text.prop" />';

alert(mytxt);

</script>
```

This is also possible, but you cant have them inside a function.You should assign relevant properties to global JS variable at the time of page load. Almost same concept slimier to use hidden variables.